# Matplotlib's set_aspect seems to not be working

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to visualize a set of coordinates using PyPlot, but I don't seem to be getting 'square' or 'equal' axes like I'm used to in MATLAB. The following script,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coords = [
          (20833.3333, 17100.0000),
          (20900.0000, 17066.6667),
          (21300.0000, 13016.6667),
          (21600.0000, 14150.0000),
          (21600.0000, 14966.6667),
          (21600.0000, 16500.0000),
          (22183.3333, 13133.3333),
          (22583.3333, 14300.0000),
          (22683.3333, 12716.6667),
          (23616.6667, 15866.6667),
          (23700.0000, 15933.3333),
          (23883.3333, 14533.3333),
          (24166.6667, 13250.0000),
          (25149.1667, 12365.8333),
          (26133.3333, 14500.0000),
          (26150.0000, 10550.0000),
          (26283.3333, 12766.6667),
          (26433.3333, 13433.3333),
          (26550.0000, 13850.0000),
          (26733.3333, 11683.3333),
          (27026.1111, 13051.9444),
          (27096.1111, 13415.8333),
          (27153.6111, 13203.3333),
          (27166.6667, 9833.3333),
          (27233.3333, 10450.0000)
          ]

x, y = zip(*coords)


plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.show()
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
```

leads to a plot which looks like this:

[image]

To me the spacing between the intervals of 1000 looks wider on the y-axis. Why is [set_aspect](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html) not working as I'd expect?

**Update**

Indeed one must set the `axes()` *before* calling `show()`. For the sake of completeness, here is how the plot is supposed to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the aspect after already viewing the plot. This worked for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coords = [
          (20833.3333, 17100.0000),
          (20900.0000, 17066.6667),
          (21300.0000, 13016.6667),
          (21600.0000, 14150.0000),
          (21600.0000, 14966.6667),
          (21600.0000, 16500.0000),
          (22183.3333, 13133.3333),
          (22583.3333, 14300.0000),
          (22683.3333, 12716.6667),
          (23616.6667, 15866.6667),
          (23700.0000, 15933.3333),
          (23883.3333, 14533.3333),
          (24166.6667, 13250.0000),
          (25149.1667, 12365.8333),
          (26133.3333, 14500.0000),
          (26150.0000, 10550.0000),
          (26283.3333, 12766.6667),
          (26433.3333, 13433.3333),
          (26550.0000, 13850.0000),
          (26733.3333, 11683.3333),
          (27026.1111, 13051.9444),
          (27096.1111, 13415.8333),
          (27153.6111, 13203.3333),
          (27166.6667, 9833.3333),
          (27233.3333, 10450.0000)
          ]

x, y = zip(*coords)


plt.plot(x, y, '.')
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

If you need to specify the size or aspect of the box, the command set_size_inches can be used. I would replace `plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')` with `plt.gcf().set_size_inches(size)` where size is a tuple of axes length in inches (eg `size=(6,6)`)